# How do you convert "final String webhookSignature = new HmacUtils(HmacAlgorithms.HMAC_SHA_1, webhookSecret).hmacHex(webhookBody);" from java to python

Tags: python, java, hmac

I'm just not experienced enough in java to figure this out, but if anyone knows the equivalent of this code in python, that would be greatly appreciated:

```
final String webhookSignature = new HmacUtils(HmacAlgorithms.HMAC_SHA_1, webhookSecret).hmacHex(webhookBody);
```

Here is the original source:
https://apidocs.rhombussystems.com/reference/simple-webhooks

Comment: Have you googled how to do an HMAC in Python? You'll need to find a Python library and read its documentation to see how to use it. It's unlikely to be a direct 1-to-1 translation.

Answer (score 1):

It should be approximately this:

```
import hmac
import hashlib

key = bytes(webhookSecret, 'UTF-8')
message = bytes(webhookBody, 'UTF-8')  
digester = hmac.new(key, message, hashlib.sha1)
signature1 = digester.hexdigest()
```